# How can I remove a field from a JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

Looking up in Node.js the database, and wants to remove `date` and `operation` fields. Do you know how? Now all the fields are sent to the FE. `collection` is refering to `MongoDB`.

```
collection.find({'recordType' : recordType, "date" : {$gte : new Date(dateFrom)}}).toArray(function(err, results) {

    response.writeHead(200)
    response.write(JSON.stringify(results));
    response.end()
});
```

Comment: Question: what do `collection` is refering to? MongoDB? a custom object that implement a find function? do you want MongoDB to return you certain field? or do you want to change that in Javascript? My answer depend on your answer.

Comment: Refering to `MongoDB`

Comment: Cool so I'll flag your question as a duplicate. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over each item and call `delete results[i].date` and `delete results[i].operation`.

You could also look into the API for the query language to see if they support something like a SELECT statement.

Comment: Perfect. I still think his question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `mongodb` then you can use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

So you can exclude fields using

```
{
  date :0,
  operation:0
}
```

So modify it to below

```
collection.find({'recordType' : recordType, "date" : {$gte : new Date(dateFrom)}},{
 date :0,
 operation:0
}).toArray(function(err, results) {

    response.writeHead(200)
    response.write(JSON.stringify(results));
    response.end()
});
```

Comment: I guess you need `'date' :0`, instead of `date :0` ?!

Comment: Nope u can fire this in mongoshell, its `json object`